# Can't save configuration after switch to production mode

Tags: magento2

After switch to production mode we set the DocumentRoot in our Apache to pub/ and seems to be working fine, however, I can't save any change in Store>Configuration, any time that I hit the Save button it keeps loading forever and never process.

Any guess?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you run static file deployment?

Comment: Yes. Still same thing.

Comment: check your permissions specifically /var folder should be writable by browser user

Comment: You should not change anything in production mode; that's not what it's for. Make your changes in developer mode. How you deploy from developer to production is up to you.